# Wrap iframe in element

Tags: javascript, angular

Our mobile app displays pre formatted html content. The content can contain iframes from YouTube. The iframe width is set to 100% but the height is a problem. If set to a fixed value, it won't look right on phone, tablet, landscape view ... etc.

I found a solution https://css-tricks.com/NetMag/FluidWidthVideo/Article-FluidWidthVideo.php, but it requires the iframe to be wrapped in another element.

The app is built using Angular 5 and Ionic

Example of an iframe which needs a wrapper:

```
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/lz1qtRK3ILg" frameborder="0" allow="autoplay; encrypted-media" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Comment: I assume you can't simply wrap your iframe in "another element" and use the linked solution, so can you explain why?

Comment: So what is the issue exactly? Are are you struggling to do? Reason you are not just setting the element around the iframe in the HTML to start?

Comment: The html content comes from multiple sources. I don't create it. I can never be sure of what will be before, after or what the iframe will be in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if this is the best solution, but it works for me:

```
@media screen and (min-width: 480px) {
    iframe {
        height: 45vw;
    }
}
```